# Entity Framework First call to stored procedure is very slow.Why?

Tags: entity-framework

New to Entity framework.

I am using EF4 and I have implemented for now Database first using Stored procedures.

I have noticed that when I launch the application and regardless which stored procedure is invoked it takes 6 seconds .After that even if call another stored procedure that has never been called before the response is fast.

Is there a trick when you create entity context for the first time?
Has anybody experiencied the same?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the view generation is performed, and it takes the most of the time.
Take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx), these recommendations should improve the situation.
More information about EF performance is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx).

Comment: Very interesting but I have to be honest I am kind of lost!! New to EF too.And My boss who asked to write a new project using EF4 is not impressed.I really want to convince him to use EF4 but I need to understand what to do and how to generate the views for my model.6 seconds for the first query is not acceptable at all.Any more suggestions would be fantastic

Comment: Also what about the fact that I am using Stored procedures.It does not seem to take into account that does it/?

Comment: Stored Procedures do not influence greatly the model initialization process (it includes Views generation). Have you tried to perform the detailed instructions from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx?

Comment: First all thanks.There is some hope then.What I was looking for is walkthrough on how to do that eg 1)do this 2)do that etc.. the msdn example is a bit vague.I would like to generate the views on every build.Are you aware of step by step instructions anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need it, but you can follow a *How to...* following this link 
[How to use a T4 template for View Generation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/06/20/how-to-use-a-t4-template-for-view-generation.aspx)